# Do the circle groups have any interesting stand-alone descriptions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory, abelian-groups

By the circle groups, I mean firstly *the* circle group $\mathbb{T} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ of all complex numbers having modulus $1$, and secondly the commutative group $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{T} \cap \{x+iy \mid x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ of all 'rational' such points.

*Edit.* I am also interested in the group $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}.$

**Question.** Do the aforementioned "circle groups" have any interesting stand-alone descriptions, not referencing the usual number systems? For example, can we describe them as the initial objects of (or free objects in) some easily-motivated category of groups? Can we define them axiomatically, as the sole models of some second-order schema of axioms?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt $\mathbb T$ has such a nice description. You could also consider the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb T$, which is the smallest group containing every finite cyclic group.

Comment: @dunstan Isn't the torsion subgroup of $\Bbb T$ isomorphic to  the group $\Bbb S$ described above?

Comment: @MJD: I think $\pm 1$ and $\pm \mathbf{i}$ are the only torsion elements in $\mathbf{S}$.

Comment: You're right; the question described $\Bbb S$, but my brain gave me the torsion group instead of what was actually described—I was thinking of the subset of points of the form $e^{2i\pi q}$ for rational $q$, instead of the set of points of the form $q$.

Comment: @MJD: It's common to look at the isomorphic group $\mathbf{R} / 1$, and the torsion group *there* is the rationals mod 1. I bet that's what went through your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is surely some phrasing of $\mathbf{T}$ as being the unique continuous group structure (up to isomorphism) on the unique compact one-dimensional manifold (up to isomorphism).

I doubt you can say anything nicer about $\mathbf{S}$ than it's the direct sum of the cyclic group on 4 elements with the free Abelian group on countably infinitely many generators. (I think that's a correct description)

Comment: Well, the way $S$ was defined it was a set that included points like $0.6+0.8i$ rather than a group. And one **can** turn such points into a group via birational (stereographic) map onto $Q$.

Comment: @Michael: The Gaussian rational numbers with unit norm are *already* a group under multiplication (and thus a subgroup of the circle group).